# modal image based on radio selet as array index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this very close but not quite. What I am looking for is to cycle images based on a radio button selection, this works fine. I would also like a modal on click of the image, so if I select radio selection 1, image name from the array shows and is clickable to a modal, similarly for each other radio option. Again, this is working fine. what is not is the modal pop up based on the radio button image.

Here is the css used:

```
#piGal ul {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 2em 3em 2em;

}
#piGal img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: .5em .5em 2em .5em;
}
#piGal .outer {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}



#piGalImg img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}


#piGalImg .outer {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}



 /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The radio button (simplified) is as follows:

```
<div class="contentText">
<section>
<h5>Choose color</h5>
<ul id="radio-attribute" class="radio-attribute">           
<li class="radio-attribute">
<label for="1" class="radio-attribute">
<input type="radio" id="1" name="id[27]" value="170" onClick="change_image(this.id)">
<img src="images/silver_swatch.png" alt="GBM0911S Silver" title=" GBM0911S Silver " width="42" height="40" />
</label>
</li>

<li class="radio-attribute">
<label for="2" class="radio-attribute">
<input type="radio" id="2" name="id[27]" value="175" onClick="change_image(this.id)">
<img src="images/blue_swatch.png" alt="GBM0911B Blue" title=" GBM0911B Blue " width="45" height="40" />
</label>
</li>
</ul>       
</section>
</div>
```

And the javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

           var images = ["GLAMOURFRONT.jpg","GBM0911S.png"];

function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img />').attr('src',this).appendTo('body').css('display','none');
    });
}

preload(images);

var galleryImage = document.querySelector("#piGalImg")
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('piGal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("piGal");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    function change_image(radioID) {
        var imageID = radioID;
        document.getElementById("piGal").innerHTML = "<img id=\"myImg\" src=\"images/"+ images[radioID] +"\" />";
    }

// Get the modal

    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }


document.getElementById("piGal").onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = "<img id=\"piGal\" src=\"images/"+ images[imageID] +"\" />";
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }


document.querySelectorAll('label.radio-attribute img').forEach(function (radioClick) {
  radioClick.addEventListener("click", function () {
//    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  });
});
//-->
</script>
```

The image rotates based on the radio selection without issue, the modal though shows the radio image name verses the image from the image array position.  I use the radio ID to determine the array element (image name) to use for the modal pop up, it is this part that is not working well.

https://jsfiddle.net/8c09e9j0/

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements on the page with the same `id="piGal"`, so `modalImg.src` is trying to set the `src` on the first element with an `id` of `pieGal`, which is not the image element in your modal. `id`'s must be unique. Change your modal ID to something unique to ensure you're trying to modify the correct element.

`<img class="modal-content" id="piGalImg">`

`var modalImg = document.getElementById("piGalImg");`

If your images are stored in an array store the index in a data-attribute on the image with the event listener and access the image array directly:

HTML:

`<img src="https://placebear.com/10/20" data-arrayid="0" alt="GBM0911B Blue" title=" GBM0911B Blue " width="45" height="40" />`

JS:

```
images = [
  '400/400.jpg',
  '400/500.jpg'
]

modalImg.src = 'https://placebear.com/' + images[this.dataset.arrayid];
```

Try this pen:
https://codepen.io/benjaminwfox/pen/yPNEWG

Comment: Tried, this did not work, the modal does not open at all now with that change.

Comment: Really not sure how to help you then. The fiddle in my answer appears to be working correctly per your question. If you can't adapt that solution to work you'll need to update your question with more complete code/more information.

Comment: Actually this is poping open the swatch color verses the array image.  the radio button switches the image so a red swatch opens a red shirt image for example, but now with this change, the red shirt does not pop opem, rather the red swatch, the image is referenced by the image array, with the radio ID corresponding to the image name position in the array.

Comment: It is in the javascript section :   var images = ["GLAMOURFRONT.jpg","GBM0911S.png"];

Comment: Oh thanks, missed that. It should be able what you want then, just concatenating the rest of the URL. I'll update to reflect that.

Comment: Your solution is good except that the radio image should not pop open, the array image should.  the radio image is only a color swatch to allow user to see the various colors available, the image switches based on the radio color selection, for example, the radio has red blue green colors, the user clicks the red radio and a red shirt displays. the displayed red shirt if clicked would then open the red shirt modal, not the red radio color swatch.  I was using the array to store the image names, and the radio ID as the index for the array to swap the "shirt" image based on the radio selected.

Comment: I think I understand...maybe :D Check the pen and see if that's the flow you're looking for. Small list image is 'swatch', clicked it shows the linked 'shirt' image, then 'shirt' image click launches bigger modal.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I need, just that it is not popping open for me even when I copy your code exactly as is.  Anyway to contact me?

Comment: @Peter Can't contact directly. Any chance you could update the question with more complete code or an updated fiddle? Another option, you might try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as you could get more complete feedback around the whole flow of your application.

Comment: If you could skype or email me, I would be interested in having you look at the page in question, remuneration can be done as well.  I am really tied up on various jobs and really would like to finish this off, with the image pop up being the last part of this.  If interested advise and will see about setting up a communication line.